Android Jetpack Compose Material 3 modifier.menuAnchor() not working properly
The modifier.menuAnchor() is not working as expected. The ExposedDropDownMenu is not anchored to the bottom of the textField, which is what I believe should be happening.
Before expanded
After expanded
If I remove the menu.anchor(), nothing appears when I expand it. See here:
no menu.Anchor() Before expanded
no menu.Anchor() After expanded
I tried researching this, but there were not many examples online, and the ones I did find seemingly do it just like I tried. Here is an image of what I expected:
expected result
UPDATE:
It appears as though the amount of DropDownMenuItems is shifting the anchor point upwards. Here is a picture using only nine items.  https://i.sstatic.net/oaZIK.png
I find this odd since my actual list has 20 items, so it is already scrollable. Is there a way to prevent it from shifting, and make it scrollable earlier?
Here is what I tried to do:
    @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
    @Composable
    fun GameDropdownMenu(gameNames: List<String>) {
        var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
        var selectedText by remember { mutableStateOf("Select Game")}

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(16.dp)
        ) {
            ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
                expanded = expanded,
                onExpandedChange = { expanded = !expanded },
                modifier = Modifier
            ) {

                TextField(
                    value = selectedText,
                    onValueChange = {},
                    readOnly = true,
                    trailingIcon = {
                        ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults.TrailingIcon(expanded = expanded)
                                   },
                    modifier = Modifier.menuAnchor().fillMaxWidth()
                )

                ExposedDropdownMenu(
                    expanded = expanded,
                    onDismissRequest = { expanded = false },
                ) {
                    gameNames.forEach { gameName ->
                        DropdownMenuItem(
                            text = { TextBodyPrimary(text = gameName, fontSize = 12.sp) },
                            onClick = {
                                selectedText = gameName
                                expanded = false

                            }
                        )
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/NJ8UO.png


Your code seems fine at first glance.  Please check that you have the correct material3 imports used for the DropdownMenuXX Composables.
import androidx.compose.material3.DropdownMenuItem
import androidx.compose.material3.ExposedDropdownMenuBox
import androidx.compose.material3.ExposedDropdownMenuDefaults
import androidx.compose.material3.TextField

Afterwards, check which version of the material3 dependency you are using. In the most recent versions, there were some changes made exactly to ExposedDropdownMenu. You can try out the latest version specifying the following dependency:
implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.3.0-alpha04"

If that doesn't resolve your issue, please create a ticket on the Google Issue Tracker and report the issue there.

Just double checked, and I do have the correct imports.

That doesn't fix the current issue, it just makes the card I have the dropDownMenu in larger.

@Lawand11 I edited my post, please have a look.
